# Calling a C++ Amp DLL on Windows HPC node fails when more than one GPGPU is installed

Tags: c#, windows, gpgpu, hpc, c++-amp

I'm attempting to call a native C++ dll with Amp code from a C# program on a Windows HPC node.  When there is only one GPGPU installed on the node, the code runs fine.  When I try to install three GPGPUs, programs freezes while trying to load the dll (it never progresses, and doesn't throw any errors).  The dll never starts at all (none of the output logging before the Amp calls are generated).  When running the code directly on the node (not through the HPC head node manager), the code runs fine.  Any ideas on how to get the code running?  Also, I'm not entirely sure what information needs to go up, so if I'm leaving out any information let me know.

EDIT:
Looking back over the logs, Windows HPC is returning an error message: Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem, Windows HPC was blocking some GPUs because the program wasn't running in a console session.  Using the same login as the running job allowed the console sessions to get created.